# R shiny tab sets simultaneous processing

Tags: shiny, tabpanel

In my R shiny app, I have many tabPanels in my tabsetPanel.

The charts of a specific tab won't begin to load until I click that tab.

So it takes a long time to just go through the contents of all tabs.

Is there any way to let all tabs process first when the app is launched so all the charts are already there when I go to different tabs?

I created a simple example with two histograms:

```
  server <- function(input, output) {
  output$distPlot <- renderPlot({
    hist(rnorm(100000000), col = 'darkgray', border = 'white')
  })


  output$distPlot2 <- renderPlot({
    hist(rnorm(100000000), col = 'red', border = 'white')
  })
  outputOptions(output,"distPlot2",suspendWhenHidden = FALSE)

}

ui <- fluidPage(

  tabsetPanel(
    tabPanel("1",plotOutput("distPlot")
      ),
    tabPanel("2",plotOutput("distPlot2")
      )
    )

)

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

I timed the loading of these two histgrams and found that the option **suspendWhenHidden = FALSE** is not working here. How to fix it?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `suspendWhenHidden` parameter for `shiny::outputOptions` to control rendering behavior:

> suspendWhenHidden. When ‘TRUE’ (the default), the output
>             object will be suspended (not execute) when it is hidden on
>             the web page. When ‘FALSE’, the output object will not
>             suspend when hidden, and if it was already hidden and
>             suspended, then it will resume immediately.

If that's not enough you can execute expensive part of you code either when application starts (outside server function), or per user (in server outside render blocks).

Comment: Hi can you take a look at my reproducible example code. I timed the loading and found that option not working as expected.

Comment: Huh, interesting. I'll take a look later and let you know if I figure out what is going on here.